# getReader() и getInputStream() в веб приложении

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

Столкнулась с проблемой что нельзя одновременно у одного request вызвать и getReader(), и getInputStream(), в документации написано что нельзя и на практике выдаёт ошибку

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getReader() has already been called for this request
```

Сервлет менять нельзя:

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Part part = request.getPart("file");
    InputStream cover = part.getInputStream();
    String id = request.getParameter(Constants.KEY_ID);
    getBookDAO().uploadBookCover(Integer.parseInt(id), cover);

}
```

Нужно в фильтре отслеживать request к этому сервлету и проверять допустимые разрешения файлов.Пока что такой набросок фильтра

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
    reader.lines().filter(str -> str.startsWith("Content-Type")).forEach(System.out::println);

    filterChain.doFilter(request, servletResponse);
}
```

Как можно иначе достать расширение файла из request или может как можно после getReader() откатить request для возможности getInputStream() ???

Comment: как вариант передавайте расширение в атрибуте запроса

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае правильным решением было бы создать два фильтра разделив функционал и объединить их в цепочку, если это конечно возможно.

В противном случае вам потребуется реализация [обертки](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestWrapper.html)  для вашего запроса, которая по сути скопирует его содержимое в буфер или кэш.

Ну и как вам подсказали в комментариях - нежелательно на уровне фильтров лезть в body, а вместо этого использовать атрибуты.